# Can MPMusicPlayerController can play music from local resource?

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaitem

i wanna play music with MPMusicPlayerController.

```
MPMediaItem * mediaItem = [];
MPMediaItemCollection *songs;
NSArray * array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:mediaItem, nil];
songs = [MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems:array];

[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] setQueueWithItemCollection:songs];
```

i don't know how to give mediaItem, and i have a mp3 file. 
Help me. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the MPMusicPlayerController will only play music from the Media Library (That's why its located in the MP/MediaPlayer framework) You'll need to use the `AVAudioPlayer` or the `AVPlayer` class. A bit more work implementing that unfortunately.

Something along the lines of this should get you started:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/audiofile.mp3",      [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

if (audioPlayer == nil)
    NSLog([error description]);
else
    [audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: If you feel this answered your question, please mark this answer as the accepted answer. Thanks :-)